# Comparison of !! operator vs present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby is there an advantage to call `present?`

```
my_value.present?
```

vs `!!`

```
!!my_value
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please? They do different things, so there is usually never any situation where you would have a choice between them.

Answer (score 5):

`.present?` is part of Rails, not a part of a standard Ruby class library. The [Rails documentation for `.present?`](https://apidock.com/rails/Object/present%3f) says that it's `true` if the object is "not blank". It's often used to determine of a database attribute has an actual value other than `nil` or blank.

```
> x = ' '
> x.present?
false
> x = nil
> x.present?
false
```

`!!` is two `!` together, a standard Ruby operator. The `!` is the Ruby logical "not" operator. A blank value is truthy in Ruby. Using two `!` together lets you take a value in Ruby and get a simple boolean `true` or `false` depending upon whether the value is truthy or falsey.

```
> x = ' '
> !!x
true    # a blank is truthy
> x = nil
> !!x
false   # nil is falsey
```

Comment: Note that in Ruby it is almost never necessary to have a simple boolean, as opposed to just a truthy/falsy value, except as a return from a question-mark function (so as not to confuse the API consumer).

Comment: @Amadan: Actually, even in question mark APIs, non-boolean values are often returned. The most famous example is probably the `defined?` unary prefix operator, which actually *never* returns a boolean value. It returns either `nil` or a string describing what is defined (e.g. `"method"` or `"local-variable"`). The point is: you shouldn't rely on this extra information. Often, question mark APIs that ask for the existence of something return `nil` to denote the absence.